# How to Set process.env.PUBLIC_URL in React App

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to React and learning different concepts. I have an application that has Public Url as '/needs-assessment/'. How do I set it to '/portfolio/needs-assessment/'. Is there a way we could programatically alter this.

Just to give a background: The Website original Url was www.abc.com/needs-assesment. So the Public_Url was /needs-assesment. However the website Url has changed and we are accessing from www.abc.com/portfolio/needs-assessment. However the PUBLIC_URL still seems to be /needs-assesment.

So a route like https://example.com/needs-assessment/210/people was matching a people component.

Now a route like https://example.com/portfolio/needs-assessment/210/people doesn't seem to match any component. It just returns a blank page.

The route in the code is something like this:-

```
<Switch>
            <TaRoute
              path={`${match.path}/people`}
              component={withAppDynamics(People)}
            />
```

Any ideas and suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From your question statement 
**process.env** will pick variables from ur **`.env`** file (**.env.development** /**.env.production** if you are using CRA ) 
and U can access variables that start with **REACT_APP_** only in react app so. 
U can use **process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL** instead of **process.env.PUBLIC_URL** and you will set its value in your **.env** file in which is in root folder of your project 

Tell me if it was helpful